# database schema for two similar users

Tags: mysql, database, logging, schema

I have a doubt about this DB schema I'm making.
I have two similar users, but one has extra information than the other:

```
Type 1 : Administrator
- Name
- Lastname
- Email
- Password

Type 2: Student
- Name
- Lastname
- Email
- Password
- Status
- Sex
- Among other type of personal information fields
```

So, I'm hesitating about either make these two separate tables, and when they're going to log in, query them both (Because I have only one logging screen), or unify them as only one table User, and make another called like "extra" with a foreign key from User pointed to the latter.

What would be the most efficent way to accomplish this? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I would make two tables and do the join after log in. Cache the extra facts about the user after they're logged in.

You should have a `User` table with these columns:

`Id, Name, Lastname, Email, Password, IsAdmin`

With a Student table:

`UserId, Status, Sex, ...`

A `Student` must also be a `User` - this will reduce duplication of data.

If you need more permissions than `IsAdmin` then remove that column and make `UserPermissions` and `Permission` tables.

If you're really that concerned about a join, then just make everything nullable and in one `User` table. I doubt it will matter in your use case (this is a much bigger topic).

Answer (score 0):

An administrator is a role played by a person.

A student is a role played by a person.

A person could play one role at a time, or maybe multiple down the road. This is a business rule and should not factor into your database schema.

Use [single table inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) to allow for different types of roles in the same table.

```
create table people (
  person_id int primary key,
  given_name varchar(...),
  surname varchar(...),
  password varchar(...)--consider a `users` table instead
);

create table roles (
  role_id int primary key,
  person_id int not null references people(person_id), --use the long-hand foreign key syntax for mysql
  type varchar(...),    --admin or student
  status varchar(...),  --consider PostgreSQL over mysql, as it supports check constraints
  sex varchar(...)
);
```